# how understanding list.index（x [，start [，end ] ] ) 's parameter using [,start[,end]]

Tags: python-3.x, list, optional-parameters, optional-arguments

Q: I don't understand list.index（x [，start [，end ] ] ）, why use this（x [，start [，end ] ] ） style, not use (x,start,end)

Comment: The brackets are a convention in the programming world for telling that such arguments are optional. In your case, you may use one, two or three arguments; and the folded  syntax tells you can use the second without the third but not the contrary. Of course you should not write theses brackets down in a piece of code; the syntax is intended to be used in documentation.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/introduction.html#notation

Answer (score 1):

The `start` and `end` arguments are optional and can be used to search only part of the list. See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 1):

The brackets mean that items in them are optional. For example,
if you remove:

```
"[, start[, end]]", you will get "list.index(x)";
```

if you remove:

```
"[, end]", you will get "list.index(x, start)"
```

instead.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter','Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall','Winter']




seasons.index('Summer', 0,3)
```

Output 1

```
seasons.index('Summer', 0,7)
```

Output 1

```
seasons.index('Summer', 3,7)
```

Output 5

```
seasons.index('Summer', 3)
```

Output 5

```
seasons.index('Summer', 0)
```

Output 1

Comment: What's the hell you trying to say?